# What Betrayal at House on the Hill scenarios can work with just two players

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Are any of the scenarios in Betrayal at House on the Hill suitable for just two players?

I'm asking as I'd  like to play just with my wife at times,  but the instructions say it requires three people minimum.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest playing with 2 characters each.

When the haunt starts, the player who controls the traitor hands their non-traitor character over to the other player to control.

Comment: This would work - you just skip any haunts that have a hidden traitor or similar.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think any would work well by default, but there are a handful that begin the haunt with removing the betrayer's character.

Those can be modified slightly in that the player isn't, then, the betrayer (and isn't removed). Play the traitor's turn as a sort of 'this is what the board does', and keep both players on the board. The game then turns into a players-vs-game game (like Pandemic, etc).

It wouldn't have the same 'feel' as the main game since there isn't a 'someone will betray us' vibe. Instead it's a 'the house will attack us' game.

I played something similar once (the player who ended up being the traitor *really* didn't want to be, so we improvised) and it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Haunt Chart, scenarios 9, 12, 31, and 50 have no traitor, just heroes, so they could likely serve your needs.  (However scenario 9 says "None (at first)" and 31 and 50 both say "None (see *Secrets of Survival*)", so scenario 12 is the only scenario that has an unequivocal lack of traitor for the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

None really work with just two players, and you don't actually make the decision on what scenario you play, the game makes that choice for you part way through. The book has a table in it which matches up omen cards with rooms they can be found in, you look up the scenario based on which open was in which room when a player loses the haunt roll. Though you could theoretically play a game like this, the haunts tend to be stacked in the traitor's favor, since the game expects it to be a many on one game at that point.